# Mysql query time increased after upgrading to ndb cluster 5.4 from 5.2

Tags: mysql

My query involves getting most recent messages between a given number and set of participants. The query involves two inner joins and an union. Total number of tables involved is two. Before upgrading from ndb cluster 5.2 to 5.4 query execution time is below 1 sec, but after upgrading without change in data i.e., table contents query execution time took more than 60 secs. I'm newbie to ndb cluster mechanism, seeking some pointers to start debugging.

select @@version: 5.6.25-ndb-7.4.7-cluster-gpl-log

Answer (score 1):

Try using EXPLAIN on statements in both 7.2 and in 7.4.

Comment: Unfortunately I lost the environment of 7.2. Anyway, there is a fundamental flaw of not having proper indexes, I'm working on it. Thanks